# Unix sort not from the first character

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I have the following data,

```
% [START_TIME - END_TIME] TURN_NAME EMOTION [V, A, D]
[6.2901 - 8.2357]   Ses01F_impro01_F000 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[10.0100 - 11.3925] Ses01F_impro01_F001 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[14.8872 - 18.0175] Ses01F_impro01_F002 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[97.8900 - 102.9600]    Ses01F_impro01_F014 neu [2.5000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[103.9700 - 106.7100]   Ses01F_impro01_F015 fru [2.0000, 3.5000, 3.0000]
[7.5712 - 10.4750]  Ses01F_impro01_M000 fru [2.5000, 2.0000, 2.5000]
[10.9266 - 14.6649] Ses01F_impro01_M001 fru [2.5000, 2.0000, 2.5000]
[16.8352 - 19.7175] Ses01F_impro01_M002 fru [2.0000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[23.4700 - 28.0300] Ses01F_impro01_M003 fru [2.5000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[101.8400 - 107.8700]   Ses01F_impro01_M013 ang [2.0000, 4.5000, 4.5000]
```

I am expecting the following result after `sort` command,

```
 % [START_TIME - END_TIME] TURN_NAME EMOTION [V, A, D]
[6.2901 - 8.2357]   Ses01F_impro01_F000 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[7.5712 - 10.4750]  Ses01F_impro01_M000 fru [2.5000, 2.0000, 2.5000]
[10.0100 - 11.3925] Ses01F_impro01_F001 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[10.9266 - 14.6649] Ses01F_impro01_M001 fru [2.5000, 2.0000, 2.5000]
[14.8872 - 18.0175] Ses01F_impro01_F002 neu [2.5000, 2.5000, 2.5000]
[16.8352 - 19.7175] Ses01F_impro01_M002 fru [2.0000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[23.4700 - 28.0300] Ses01F_impro01_M003 fru [2.5000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[97.8900 - 102.9600]    Ses01F_impro01_F014 neu [2.5000, 3.5000, 3.5000]
[101.8400 - 107.8700]   Ses01F_impro01_M013 ang [2.0000, 4.5000, 4.5000]
[103.9700 - 106.7100]   Ses01F_impro01_F015 fru [2.0000, 3.5000, 3.0000]
```

I used the following `sort` command to order from the second character,

```
 sort -k1.2 filename
```

But it gives the first line of `[10.0100....]`. So, the sort command will order based on the most left decimal number (START_TIME) while kept the header on the top. Any experienced `sort` user here can help...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify you want **numeric** sorting with the `-g` option:

```
{ read -r header; echo "$header"; sort -g -k 1.2,1; } < filename
```

Comment: Works perfectly as expected. Thank you for the lesson!